# gsl_rng_default Unresolved External Error

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, gsl

Trying to use GSL to generated beta-distributed random deviates in C on windows.  Program will not link, giving the well known "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gsl_rng_default" error message.

Problem is *not* with the general installation of GSL.  I can compile and call cdf functions just fine.  But, for the record:

Program has the following includes:

`#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>`

`#include <gsl/gsl_cdf.h>`

`#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>`

Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories points to the GSL-1.15\include directory.

Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories points to the GSL-1.15\lib directory.

Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies has two entries, libgsl.dll.a and libgslcblas.dll.a

Program compiles and links if the line `T = gsl_rng_default;`is removed.
With `T = gsl_rng_default;` the program compiles does not link.

Tried including GSL_DLL as a preprocessor definition.  No effect on problem.

Tried `#define GSL_DLL` at top of program. Still has no effect on the problem.

Tried all setting options under Configuration Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library.  No effect on problem.

Is there another switch that has to be thrown to make this work with Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 2):

Add "GSL_DLL" to Configuration -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definition.